# Azure Function app periodically not firing on trigger or timer

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function app with 4 functions

- one triggered on a timer every 24 hours
- one triggered on events from IoT Hub
- two others triggered on events from Service Bus as a result of the previous function

All functions work as expected when first deployed but after a period of time the functions stop running and the app appears to be scaled down with no servers online. At this point the functions are never triggered again unless I either restart the app, or drill into a function and view details of it (supposedly, forcing the function to start up).

I have the exact same code deployed to a different environment and it runs perfectly and has never encountered this issue. I've checked all the settings and configuration and can't see any material differences between the two.

This is really frustrating and is becoming a big issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

Function App is hosted in **Australia Southeast**.

This is the last execution (as of now)
**10:45 PM UTC - Function started (Id=4d29555b-d3af-43d7-95e9-1a4a2d43dc46)**

The event triggered function should run every few minutes as the IoT Hub it's triggering from has a steady stream of events coming in. When I prod the function (or restart it) and it comes to life it quickly churns through a backlog of messages queued in the IoT Hub.

Comment: Can you share your function app name (that's the **app** name, not function name!), either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately)? Also, a sample UTC time where it should have fired and didn't.

Comment: Have you checked what causes the scale down? A network traffic rule/Firewall ? Is the working environment in a different region or contains different networking settings ?

Comment: Thanks @DavidEbbo - I've updated the question with details

Comment: @AdamSmith-MSFT where would I find detail about what causes it to scale down? Given the timer trigger doesn't even fire (once scaled down) then I assumed it's nothing network related.

Comment: @Richard how did you deploy your Function App?

Comment: @DavidEbbo deployed via Visual Studio publish. I used the same mechanism with the other working environment.

Comment: @Richard see my Answer below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see the problem: you have comments in your host.json, which makes it invalid and throws off the parser at the scale controller level.

Admittedly, the error handling is quite poor here. But anyway, remove the commented out logger, and it should all work.

Comment: Thanks David, I've removed the comment and redeployed. I'll let you know if that resolves the issue.

Comment: @Richard I checked the backend and your triggers look healthy now. I suspect all will be well.

Comment: Awesome, looks pretty good on my end too. Thanks so much for your prompt response and help.